# No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager

Tags: spring-data-jpa

> No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

To solve this error, we had to rename the transaction manager to the default name.

```java
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTxManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(clientDestinationDataSource());
    }
```

```java
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
    @Override
    public Long processClient(Client client) {
```

```java
@Autowired
    public UpdateStrategy(Repository repository,
                                        ...
                                         @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
        super(repository,... txManager);
    }
```

it is unclear why a custom name cannot be used. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The first one with the @Bean(name="transactionManager" is what you expected to provide the bean for the @Autowired?  try naming the method transactionManager and se if that does it

Answer (score 0):

- To check all the valid depend lib (Hibernate)
- Using JPA
- May be useful of below code to configure.

  ```
  @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
       public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
           LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
           sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
           sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.ashok.api.repository" );
       sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
           return sessionFactory;
  ```

---

```
 @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface ashokRepository extends CrudRepository<ashokDBs, Long>
```